# Why the total nuclear spin is only 0 or 2 for singlet s-wave scatting with $M_F=0$?

Tags: scattering, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity, cold-atoms

when I read the [lecture](http://www.phlam.univ-lille1.fr/leshouches/cours14/Walraven5.pdf) of Feshbach resonance, the lecture on page 15 said that it want to find all s-wave molecules for $M_F=0$. It said when the two atoms are singlet, the total nuclear spin is only 0 or 2 for s-wave scatting. I don't know why that happened. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For this atoms, the s=1/2 and i=1, the atoms are fermions. So the wave function of the two atoms is anti-symmetry for exchange. For electric spin singlet, the wave function of electric spin is anti-symmetry for exchange. So the total wave function of nuclear spin and space wave function should be symmetry for exchange. For I=0,2, the nuclear spin is symmetry, then the space wave function should be symmetry. So l=0,2,4,6....